# Why is urine acidic (equilibrium of I/O, input <=> output)

Tags: kidney

Urine pH is on average 6.0, net excretion of acid. Is that in balance with net input of acid?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. The answer to your question is, of course, no. Have you tried to [research this question yourself](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? Acid–Base balance is an important topic and there are numerous introductory articles such as [this one](http://www.anaesthesiamcq.com/AcidBaseBook/ab2_1.php) about it on the web. If after doing a little reading, you still have specific problems, repost letting us know precisely what they are. (There's no chemical law of conservation of acidity, you know.)

Comment: consumption of meat (acidic) will be handled by increased excretion of acid via the lungs though, carbon dioxide, and since the kidney is the major organ for acid-base regulation, it seems very likely that its normal rate of excretion of acid was a result of equilibrium of "acid-in, acid-out", since it will increase acidity of urine to respond to acidosis, or alkalinity for alkalosis, etc.

Comment: Please finish reading the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how this site works. If you wish to answer your own question you may do so, but as an answer, not a comment. My own comment was an attempt to improve your question by making it more specific, given that this is such a wide area. Although I expressed an opinion, I was not answering your question (by explaining why) but suggesting where you could read about the counter-view to the one that seemed implicit in your question and may have been the result of erroneous chemical assumptions.

Comment: well if average kidney pH has nothing to do with acid-base regulation (while urine pH clearly does often reflect acid-base regulation), and it is more about antibacterial properties or similar, that'd be an answer too. idk if the question is out of place, since clearly acidic diet (or, one that generates surplus acid in body) would tend to acid-base regulation compensation by acidic urine.